# how to upload larger file( greater than 12 MB) to aws s3 bucket in using salesforce apex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, salesforce

I need some help for uploading large files into s3 bucket from salesforce apex server side.

I need to be able to split a blob and upload it to aws s3 bucket using Http PUT operation. I am able to do that upto 12 MB file in a single upload because that is the PUT request body size limit in Apex .
So i need to be able to upload using multipart operation. I noticed s3 allows to upload in parts and gives back a uploadId. wondering if anyone has already done this before in salesforce apex code. it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Parbati Bose.

Here is the code

```
public with sharing class AWSS3Service {

    private static Http http;

    @auraEnabled
    public static  void uploadToAWSS3( String fileToUpload , String filenm , String doctype){


        fileToUpload = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(fileToUpload, 'UTF-8');

        filenm = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filenm , 'UTF-8'); // encode the filename in case there are special characters in the name 
        String filename = 'Storage' + '/' + filenm ;
        String attachmentBody = fileToUpload;

        String formattedDateString = DateTime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');




        // s3 bucket!
        String key = '**********' ;
        String secret = '********' ;
        String bucketname = 'testbucket' ;
        String region = 's3-us-west-2' ;



        String host = region + '.' + 'amazonaws.com' ; //aws server base url




    try{
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        http = new Http() ;
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + bucketname + '.' + host +  '/' +  filename );
        req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);

        req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type' , doctype);
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
        req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');


        String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' +
                doctype + '\n' +
                formattedDateString + '\n' +
                '/' + bucketname +  '/' + filename;


        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(secret));
        String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
        String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signed;
        req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);

        req.setBodyAsBlob(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileToUpload)) ;



        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);

        Log.debug('response from aws s3 is ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' and ' + response.getBody());


    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.debug('error in connecting to s3 ' + e.getMessage());
            throw e ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you ever found a solution for this? I can see answer was marked as the one, but I dont see how could you transalte SDK code into APEX

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The AWS SDK for Java exposes a high-level API, called TransferManager,
>   that simplifies multipart uploads (see Uploading Objects Using
>   Multipart Upload API). You can upload data from a file or a stream.
>   You can also set advanced options, such as the part size you want to
>   use for the multipart upload, or the number of concurrent threads you
>   want to use when uploading the parts. You can also set optional object
>   properties, the storage class, or the ACL. You use the
>   PutObjectRequest and the TransferManagerConfiguration classes to set
>   these advanced options.

Here is the sample code from  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html.

You can adapt to your Salesforce Apex code:

```
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Upload;

import java.io.File;

public class HighLevelMultipartUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String keyName = "*** Object key ***";
        String filePath = "*** Path for file to upload ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();
            TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                    .withS3Client(s3Client)
                    .build();

            // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
            // so this call returns immediately.
            Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
            System.out.println("Object upload started");

            // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
            upload.waitForCompletion();
            System.out.println("Object upload complete");
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Juned for your reply. But this is a java package with bunch of apis. You mean to translate the whole package into apex code ?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this same issue in the last couple of days, unfortunately you are going to be better performing this transfer from outside of Salesforce due to the APEX Heap size limit of 12MB.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Whilst it would be possible to write files using multipart, it seems you cannot get them out of the database for splitting them into chunks you can send. A similar question was asked on the stackexchange -
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264015/how-to-retrieve-file-content-from-content-document-in-chunks-using-soql